# How to get lipsum to accept a count as a parameter

Tags: counters, parameters, lipsum

I get the error: `Missing number, treated as zero.` trying to pass a counter to `\lipsum`. I feel like I might be forgetting some basic technique here, but I've unsuccessfully scoured the site to find out why the following doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcount\zz
\loop
\lipsum[\zz]
\advance\zz1
\ifnum\zz<60
\repeat

\end{document}
```

In case anyone's wondering why I would bother with this, when `\lipsum[1-60]` gives me all those paragraphs, it's because it gives them all in one go, whereas I want to add something to each element, so there would be other lines of code added to the loop.

In particular, the loop enables me to use the counter value, which is part of the reason for using a loop in the first place.

Comment: In addition, you can use `\lipsum[1-10]`, for example.

Comment: @Sigur Thank you, but I know how to use that. I'll update my question to point out that the loop is necessary, because I want to be able to add something to each element from lipsum.

Comment: @GeoffPointer You can use `\setlipsum{par-end={stuff}}` to add `stuff` after each paragraph: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\setlipsum{par-end={stuff}}
\lipsum[1-60]
\end{document}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you, but that doesn't enable me to use the counter value, which is part of the reason for using a loop. I've updated my question further. None the less your tip may be useful to avoid another question that was brewing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\the\zz`.  `lipsum` currently sacrifices some flexibility (like using a count directly) to parse number ranges (like `2-5`).  A more robust parser would solve the problem, but using `\the` is guaranteed to work:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newcount\zz
\loop
\lipsum[\the\zz]
\advance\zz1
\ifnum\zz<60
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd use `expl3` for the job.

The command `\lipsumloop` has four arguments

- `#1` (optional, default 1) for the starting point
- `#2` for the end point
- `#3` is the material to be printed before the paragraph
- `#4` is the material to be printed after the paragraph

In the last two arguments you can use `#1` to stand for the current lipsum paragraph number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\lipsumloop}{O{1} m +m +m}
 {% #1 = start point, #2 = end point, #3 = pre, #4 = post
  \int_step_inline:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 \lipsum[##1] #4 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lipsumloop[3]{6}{\par\addvspace{1ex}This is lipsum #1: \\}{~\textbullet~End of lipsum #1\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. For me, a whole new wormhole to get lost in.